# Javascript Regexp split by multiple characters and keeping separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split by the following by multiple characters and keep them in the array.

split by: &&, ||, (, )

```
"arg&&(arg||(!arg&&arg))".split(/([)||&&(])/);
```

My return is suppose to look like this:

```
["arg","&&","(","arg","||","(","!arg","&&","arg",")",")"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing groups are kept in resulting array.

`|` should be escaped, because it have special meaning in regular expression. `(` and `)` also have special meaning, but inside `[]`, they match literally.

```
> "arg&&(arg||(!arg&&arg))".split(/([()]|&&|\|\|)/)
["arg", "&&", "", "(", "arg", "||", "", "(", "!arg", "&&", "arg", ")", "", ")", ""]
```

To remove empty string, use [`Array filter method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
> "arg&&(arg||(!arg&&arg))".split(/([()]|&&|\|\|)/).filter(function(x) { return x; })
["arg", "&&", "(", "arg", "||", "(", "!arg", "&&", "arg", ")", ")"]
```